# How do I prevent my application's controls from displaying in the iOS Control Center?

Tags: ios, iphone, control-center

I'm creating an iOS application that is ***not*** a music playing app, but anytime the app is running I can see it in the iOS Control Center and it has the same controls as a music-playing application would.

I don't want my application to appear in the Control Center at all. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? If not, is there at least a way I can make it not look like a music application?

Here is an example of what it looks like right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO2JO.jpg

Comment: What's the object you use to play sound/videos ?

Comment: We are using AVAudioPlayer to play sound.

Comment: It's been a while since I didn't play with `AVAudioPlayer`, but did you implement `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` (that give the info to that center) ?

Comment: We did not implement       MPNowPlayingInfoCenter

Comment: Did you implement `remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:`? Anyway, even if you fixed this, it might not clear until another app registers itself. Try starting the music app and playing something.

Comment: We didn't implement remoteControlReceivedWithEvent either, but we stopped using beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents and when I opened another music playing application, my application doesn't appear in the Control Center anymore. Thanks for the tip, @MarcusAdams!